# Selenium suddenly can't start Firefox / geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I used to start Firefox in headless mode through selenium for couple of days. And suddenly the initialization of geckodriver began to fail!

This is a minimal python script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
```

And this is the error it produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/pye/e1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=self.options)
  File "/root/pye/e1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/root/pye/e1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/root/pye/e1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/root/pye/e1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Socket timeout reading Marionette handshake data: Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11)
```

As I said, this worked for some time until now. Also now I was accidentially able to run geckodriver, but most of the time it fails with the above error message.

My system:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
# python -V
Python 3.8.10
# pip show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 4.10.0
# firefox -version
Mozilla Firefox 113.0.2
# geckodriver -V
geckodriver 0.33.0 ( 2023-05-22)
```

I updated selenium from 4.9.1 to 4.10.0, but it didn't help.